# Cannot Resolve Intent Constructor

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an app that uses the Reddit API to display a bunch of posts in a listview. When you click on a post in the listview, the plan is to open a detailactivity that shows some of the details of the post. I've got some problems making it work, however.

This is the code I'm using in the mainactivity class (where the listview is displayed):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.facebook.drawee.backends.pipeline.Fresco;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final Context context = this;
        Fresco.initialize(context);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        addFragment();

        View listview = findViewById(R.id.posts_list);
        listview.setOnClickListener (new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View p_view,
                                    int p_pos, long arg3) {


                TextView text = (TextView ) p_view.findViewById(R.id.post_link); //id of textview from layout file that you are inflating.

                CharSequence mytext=text.getText();
                Intent i = new Intent(this, DetailActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("text",mytext);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

    };

    void addFragment(){
        getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragments_holder
                        , PostsFragment.newInstance("wallpapers"))
                .commit();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Whenever a list item is clicked, the text in the textview with id "post_link" will be sent to the new activity so I can display it in there.

The problem is with the line `Intent i = new Intent(this, DetailActivity.class);`. Android Studio says it cannot resolve the constructor. I tried a few solutions from the other questions, but these didn't work, sadly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DetailActivity.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you inside a Fragment? In which case the you code should look like

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DetailActivity.class);
```

Or you can hold a reference to the context and use that instead of `getActivity()`

Comment: Getting the error "Cannot resolve method 'getActivity()' now.

Comment: Are you inside a Fragment or Activity? Can you post the enclosing classes code?

Comment: I've updated code and changed "this" - to " getApplicationContext()" - there's no reason why this shouldn't work! Clean/Rebuild your project, and hopefully it will work

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(First.this, Second.class);
intent.putExtra("mytext","" +p_pos);
startActivity (intent)
```

Comment: Tried it out, but now I get the error "setOnClickListener (android.view.View.OnClickListener) in View cannot be applied to (anonymous android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener)

Tried changing the android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener to android.view.View.OnClickListener and changing the  `public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View p_view,
                                    int p_pos, long arg3) {1 ` into `public void onClick(View view) {`, but that throws a NullPointerException.

Comment: The problem persists, sadly.

Comment: try now :) hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), DetailActivity.class);
```